# how to Inject Calendar getInstance in Spring , please

Tags: java, spring

**`<bean id="date" class="java.util.Calendar.getInstance" />`**

how can i inject Calendar instance Please help

i am confused what to use ,i am new to spring  In date where new keyword is required is fine but here what have to do

Comment: Why would you want your date to be a bean in the spring context? replace `class` with `factory-method`.

Comment: As an aside, the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `<bean>` declaration `class` should specify the complete classname. `getInstance` is a factory method & hence it should be as follows:

```
<bean id="date" class="java.util.Calendar" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

It might be better to use the `java.time` classes introduced in Java 8, rather than the old `java.util.Calendar` & `java.util.Date`.

```
<bean id="date" class="java.time.LocalDate" factory-method="now">
```

**NB:** Nevertheless, I can't think of a valid use case, to have the date as a bean.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR ANSWER

Comment: @LEARNEROLYASKING Could you please stop shouting (all caps is considered shouting)?